# parallel lines in tikz

Tags: tikz-3dplot

I have this code of two lines and I want to plot two parallel lines to those lines and then connet the opposite corners together .. is there a simple way to do it

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}   %TikZ is required for this to work.  Make sure this exists before the next line

\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} %requires 3dplot.sty to be in same directory, or in your LaTeX installation

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}  %generates a tightly fitting border around the work
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rvec}{.8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\thetavec}{30}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\phivec}{60}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\draw[-stealth,thick] (O) -- (P);
\draw[-stealth,thick] (O) -- (Pxy);
\tdplotdrawarc{(O)}{0.2}{0}{\phivec}{anchor=north}{$\phi$}
\tdplotsetthetaplanecoords{\phivec}
\tdplotdrawarc[tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{0.5}{0}{\thetavec}{anchor=south west}{$\theta$}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\phivec}{\thetavec}{0}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoordsorigin{(P)}  
\tdplotsetrotatedthetaplanecoords{45}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Pleas extend your code snippet to complete bu small and compilable document!

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand, should I include a figure?

Comment: @Diana No :-) You should improved your code putting all the packages and \documentclass.

Comment: In your MWE aren't define coordinate `P`. command `\rdplotalpha` ... Please make your MWE compilable. Also a sketch, what you like to obtain would be helpful.